# Creating Point in GeoDataFrage gives Error: unhashable type: 'Point'

Tags: python, geopandas, shapley

Im trying to create a new geodataframe with a point as one of the Attributes. It's all going to happen in a loop in the end, as I then want to concat multiple gdf's into one, but what is giving me a headache is this part:

```
        from shapely.geometry import Point
        import geopandas as gpd
        
        ptX = 13.435621213 #row2['geometry'].x
        ptY = 52.480377234 #row2['geometry'].y
        gdf_this = gpd.GeoDataFrame({('name', Point(ptX, ptY))})
```

as it gives the Error:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'`

I assume it has something to do with the reference vs copy thing, so I've tried creating a temporary point first and then using

`gdf_this = gpd.GeoDataFrame({('name', copy.deepcopy(temp_point))})`

but that gives the same error.

The documentation for shapely.Points lists a method `reverse()` which is supposed to return a copy of the geometry, but `Point(ptX, ptY).reverse()` gives the Error `AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'reverse'`?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps you better to consider:

**1. Resolving the TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point':**

Use a list of tuples: GeoDataFrame expects a list of tuples for its data, even when creating a single-row DataFrame. Here's the corrected code:

```
gdf_this = gpd.GeoDataFrame([('name', Point(ptX, ptY))])
```

**2. Clarifying the AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'reverse':**

Shapely's reverse() method: It's primarily used for line-like geometries (LineStrings, MultiLineStrings) to reverse their coordinates. Points don't have a meaningful "reverse" operation, hence the error.
Corrected code for creating multiple GeoDataFrames and concatenating them:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Assuming you have your data in a list of tuples
data = [
    ('name1', 13.435621213, 52.480377234),
    ('name2', 15.6789, 49.1234),
    # ... more data
]

# Create a list to store the individual GeoDataFrames
gdf_list = []

for name, x, y in data:
    point = Point(x, y)
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([(name, point)], columns=['name', 'geometry'])
    gdf_list.append(gdf)

# Concatenate the GeoDataFrames
gdf_final = gpd.concat(gdf_list)
print(gdf_final)
```

Comment: Thank you! Using tuples did the trick. ps: I knew reverse() didn't make much sense for a point - but the doc said that points would just be copied, so I tried anyway...